# How to popup alertbox in android app for exiting when i am already using onBackPressed() for webviews to go back?

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

I want my app should show alert box on exiting the app but if I try to add code for alertbox in onBackPressed() application closes forcibly.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (Fragment1.canGoBack()) {
            Fragment1.goBack();
        }
        if (Fragment2.canGoBack()) {
            Fragment2.goBack();
        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

this is the code for the webviews to make those views to go back.Where should i add alertbox for exiting the app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `super.onBackPressed()` immediately, first show alert dialog and when user presses button, call `super.onBackPressed()`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean wentBack = false;

    if (Fragment1.canGoBack()) {
        wentBack = true;
        Fragment1.goBack();
    }
    if (Fragment2.canGoBack()) {
        wentBack = true;
        Fragment2.goBack();
    }

    if (!wentBack) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Quit app?")
            .setMessage("Do you want to quit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> super.onBackPressed())
            .setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {})
            .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point you might as well call `finish()` to end the activity instead of relying on super method.

Comment: bro I used it in the code it worked but the problem is whenever I click back button even if I am in 2nd or 3rd page in webview it shows alertbox every time @ElectroWeak